# How to generate a lightning invoice of any type offline

Tags: lightning-network, invoices, atomic-multi-path-payments, bolt12-offers, bolt11

Is it possible to generate a lightning network invoice without the encumbrance of a full lightning node (lightning node defined as: fully synced channel graph, knowledge of channel outpoints, and current channel state)?

How about bolt11, bolt12, amp invoices? Any other methods?